# How to flatten nested array of object using es6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have this array of objects, within it I have another array of objects:

```
[
  {
    id: 1,
    country: [
      {
        id: "5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a85"
      },
      {
        id: "5a6062661d41c80c8b2f0413"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    country: [
      {
        id: "5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a83"
      },
      {
        id: "5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a84"
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

How to get flat array of `country` like this:

```
[
  { id: "5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a85" },
  { id: "5a6062661d41c80c8b2f0413" },
  { id: "5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a83" },
  { id: "5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a84" }
];
```

without using a `forEach` and a temp variable?

When I did:

```
(data || []).map(o=>{
  return o.country.map(o2=>({id: o2.id}))
})
```

I got the same structure back.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

#### Latest edit

All modern JS environments now support [`Array.prototype.flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [`Array.prototype.flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap)

```js
const data=[{id:1,country:[{id:"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a85"},{id:"5a6062661d41c80c8b2f0413"}]},{id:2,country:[{id:"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a83"},{id:"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a84"}]}];

console.log(
  data.flatMap(
    (elem) => elem.country
  )
)
```

---

#### Old answer

No need for any ES6 magic, you can just reduce the array by concatenating inner `country` arrays.

```js
const data=[{id:1,country:[{id:"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a85"},{id:"5a6062661d41c80c8b2f0413"}]},{id:2,country:[{id:"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a83"},{id:"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a84"}]}];

console.log(
  data.reduce(
    (arr, elem) => arr.concat(elem.country), []
  )
)
```

If you want an ES6 feature (other than an arrow function), use array spread instead of the concat method:

```js
const data=[{id:1,country:[{id:"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a85"},{id:"5a6062661d41c80c8b2f0413"}]},{id:2,country:[{id:"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a83"},{id:"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a84"}]}];

console.log(
  data.reduce(
    (arr, elem) => [...arr, ...elem.country], []
  )
)
```

Note: These suggestions would create a new array on each iteration.

For efficiency, you have to sacrifice some elegance:

```js
const data=[{id:1,country:[{id:"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a85"},{id:"5a6062661d41c80c8b2f0413"}]},{id:2,country:[{id:"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a83"},{id:"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a84"}]}];

console.log(
  data.reduce(
    (arr, elem) => {
      for (const c of elem.country) {
        arr.push(c);
      }
      return arr;
    }, []
  )
)
```

Comment: spread work if my country only have id property, which usually is not the case.

Comment: what if I want ['id1','id2','id3','id4'] will I still use reduce?

Comment: You can just insert `country.map(({ id }) => id)` instead of `country` in any of the examples.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const raw = [
  {
    id: 1,
    country: [
      {
        id: "5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a85"
      },
      {
        id: "5a6062661d41c80c8b2f0413"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    country: [
      {
        id: "5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a83"
      },
      {
        id: "5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a84"
      }
    ]
  }
];

const countryIds = raw
                    .map(x => x.country)
                    .reduce((acc, curr) => {
                      return [
                        ...acc, 
                        ...curr.map(x => x.id)
                      ];
                    }, []);
console.log(countryIds)
```

Answer (score 0):

This, works, just concat the nested arrays returned by your solution

```js
let arr = [{    "id": 1,
    "country": [{
        "id": "5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a85",
      },
      {
        "id": "5a6062661d41c80c8b2f0413",
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "country": [{
        "id": "5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a83",
      },
      {
        "id": "5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a84",
      }
    ]
  }
];

//If you want an array of country objects
console.log([].concat.apply(...(arr || []).map(o=> o.country)))

//If you can an array od country ids
console.log([].concat.apply(...(arr || []).map(o=> o.country.map(country => country.id))))
```

Comment: what if I don't want object, I want pure id in my array?

Comment: You mean something like `[ '5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a85', '5a6062661d41c80c8b2f0413', '5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a83', '5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a84' ]`?

Comment: Saw the answer, concat is too confusing, any es6 code?

Comment: The `reduce` answer posted by @nem035 is the ES6 equivalent of this

Answer (score 0):

Ayush Gupta's solution will work for this case. But I would like to provide other solution.

```js
const arr = [
  {
    id: 1,
    country: [
      {
        id: '5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a85'
      },
      {
        id: '5a6062661d41c80c8b2f0413'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    country: [
      {
        id: '5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a83'
      },
      {
        id: '5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a84'
      }
    ]
  }
];

const ids = arr.reduce(
  (acc, {country}) => [
    ...acc,
    ...country.map(({id}) => ({
      id
    }))
  ],
  []
);
console.log(ids);
```

Comment: what if country's array have other property? I just want to have the id.

Answer (score 0):

For JSON string data, it can be done during parsing too :

```js
var ids = [], json = '[{"id":1,"country":[{"id":"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a85"},{"id":"5a6062661d41c80c8b2f0413"}]},{"id":2,"country":[{"id":"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a83"},{"id":"5a60626f1d41c80c8d3f8a84"}]}]';

JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => v.big && ids.push(v));

console.log( ids );
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure why noone mentioned `flat()` (probably for large arrays, it might be less performant)

```
(data || []).map(o=>{
  return o.country.map(o2=>({id: o2.id}))
}).flat()
```