# Flatten nested array of objects, renaming keys to an iterator

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, lodash, flatten

I have an array of objects, with each object looking like the following (a poll response):

```
{
"slug": "18-AZ-Gov-GE-DvF",
"name": "2018 Arizona Gubernatorial GE",
"tags": [],
"charts": [],
"election_date": "2018-11-06",
"n_polls": 1,
"created_at": "2017-06-13T13:32:26.000Z",
"responses": [
 {
 "label": "Ducey",
 "name": "Doug Ducey",
 "party": "Republican",
 "incumbent": true
 },
 {
 "label": "Farley",
 "name": "Steve Farley",
 "party": "Democrat",
 "incumbent": false
 },
 {
 "label": "Other",
 "name": "Other",
 "party": null,
 "incumbent": false
 },
 {
 "label": "Undecided",
 "name": "Undecided",
 "party": null,
  "incumbent": false
 }
]
},
```

I need to flatten the array accessed by the `responses` key so that each object keyed to its iterator.

**The final object should look like:**

```
{
"slug": "18-AZ-Gov-GE-DvF",
"name": "2018 Arizona Gubernatorial GE",
"tags": [],
"charts": [],
"election_date": "2018-11-06",
"n_polls": 1,
"created_at": "2017-06-13T13:32:26.000Z",
 "label1": "Ducey",
 "name1": "Doug Ducey",
 "party1": "Republican",
 "incumbent1": true
 "label2": "Farley",
 "name2": "Steve Farley",
 "party2": "Democrat",
 "incumbent2": false
 "label3": "Other",
 "name3": "Other",
 "party3": null,
 "incumbent3": false
 "label4": "Undecided",
 "name4": "Undecided",
 "party4": null,
  "incumbent4": false
},
```

The [answers I've seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435515/how-to-flatten-nested-array-of-object-using-es6) do not rename the object keys when flattening or are performed on a collection.

I've tried several solutions, but wanted to see if there's an easy es6 way before I really dive in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach would use a few of the newer goodies including [`spread`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), [`destructuring assignment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), [`template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), [`entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and most importantly [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

The main gist is using a reducer to convert the `responses` array to a new object with each element object using a secondary reducer to amend the key with the iterator count and assigning the value to the outer object with the new key.

A key benefit of this approach is the original object (including its sub-objects) are not modified (read: no side-effects).

```js
const flattened = responses.reduce((o, g, i) => {
    Object.entries(g).reduce((t, [k, v]) => {
      t[`${k}${i + 1}`] = v;
      return t;
    }, o);

    return o;
  },
  {});
```

Full working example:

```js
const orig = {
  "slug": "18-AZ-Gov-GE-DvF",
  "name": "2018 Arizona Gubernatorial GE",
  "tags": [],
  "charts": [],
  "election_date": "2018-11-06",
  "n_polls": 1,
  "created_at": "2017-06-13T13:32:26.000Z",
  "responses": [{
      "label": "Ducey",
      "name": "Doug Ducey",
      "party": "Republican",
      "incumbent": true
    },
    {
      "label": "Farley",
      "name": "Steve Farley",
      "party": "Democrat",
      "incumbent": false
    },
    {
      "label": "Other",
      "name": "Other",
      "party": null,
      "incumbent": false
    },
    {
      "label": "Undecided",
      "name": "Undecided",
      "party": null,
      "incumbent": false
    }
  ]
};

const {responses, ...foo} = orig;
const flattened = responses.reduce((o, g, i) => {
    Object.entries(g).reduce((t, [k, v]) => {
      t[`${k}${i + 1}`] = v;
      return t;
    }, o);

    return o;
  },
  {});

console.log({flattened: {...foo, ...flattened}});
console.log({orig});
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the array `.reduce` method might work well here. Since the `reduce` callback will receive the current index as the third argument, you can use that to create the keys you're looking for.

Example:

```js
const myArray = [
 {
 "label": "Ducey",
 "name": "Doug Ducey",
 "party": "Republican",
 "incumbent": true
 },
 {
 "label": "Farley",
 "name": "Steve Farley",
 "party": "Democrat",
 "incumbent": false
 },
 {
 "label": "Other",
 "name": "Other",
 "party": null,
 "incumbent": false
 },
 {
 "label": "Undecided",
 "name": "Undecided",
 "party": null,
  "incumbent": false
 }
]

const flattened = myArray.reduce((flat, item, index) => ({
    ...flat,
    ...Object.keys(item).reduce((numbered, key) => ({
        ...numbered,
        [key + (index+1)]: item[key],
    }), {}),
}), {});

console.log(flattened);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `forEach` to go through the `responses` array and assign a new key on your object for the `entries` in each object. After that just `delete` the original `responses` array:

```js
let obj = {"slug": "18-AZ-Gov-GE-DvF","name": "2018 Arizona Gubernatorial GE","tags": [],"charts": [],"election_date": "2018-11-06","n_polls": 1,"created_at": "2017-06-13T13:32:26.000Z","responses": [ { "label": "Ducey", "name": "Doug Ducey", "party": "Republican", "incumbent": true }, { "label": "Farley", "name": "Steve Farley", "party": "Democrat", "incumbent": false }, { "label": "Other", "name": "Other", "party": null, "incumbent": false }, { "label": "Undecided", "name": "Undecided", "party": null,  "incumbent": false }]}

obj.responses.forEach((item, i) => {
        // item is one object from responses
        // i is the index starting at 0. Concat that on the key
        Object.entries(item).forEach(([k, v]) => obj[k+(i+1)] = v)
    })
// no need for obj.responses any more
delete obj.responses
console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure your responses and other data, then reduce each response to one object with indexed keys and then assemble result by object spread operator:

```
const { responses, ...other } = data
const indexedResponses = responses.reduce((acc, r, i) => {
  Object.entries(r).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    acc[`${key}${i + 1}`] = value
  })
  return acc
}, {})
const result = { ...other, ...indexedResponses }
```