# Grouping a object value inside n level nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array like this. How to group all child Ids into an array?
My solution below is not giving me all child elements. Where is the mistake? and suggest me any other ways

```js
const data = {
  name: '1',
  id: '05f770d5',

  child: [
    {
      name: '2',
      id: '0ecfc8e1',
      child: [
        {
          name: '3',
          id: '2e1eb75c',
          child: [],
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      name: '1c',
      id: 'b9ee9864',
      child: [
        {
          name: '8',
          id: '575f4760',
          child: [],
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
};

let array1 = [];

function sumChild(data) {
  data.child.forEach((data) => {
    array1.push(data.id);
    sumChild(data?.child[0]);
  });

  return array1;
}

sumChild(data);

console.log(array1);
```

Comment: do you have a wanted result of all?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generate a flat array of ids from a multilevel tree using reduce function with recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55064535/generate-a-flat-array-of-ids-from-a-multilevel-tree-using-reduce-function-with-r)

Comment: Yes.I want all child elements in array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function sumChild(data) {
  data.child?.forEach((data) => {
    array1.push(data.id);
    sumChild(data);
  });

  return array1;
}
```