# How can I get the values from an array inside an array?

Tags: javascript

In the below examples, why am I not getting any value?

```js
const people = [{
    name: "mike",
    jobs: ["waiter", "doctor"]
  },
  {
    name: "nils",
    jobs: ["singer", "actor"]
  },
  {
    name: "nils",
    jobs: ["nurse", "actor"]
  },
]


const iterate = people.map(person => {
  return person.jobs.map(job => {
    return job;
  })
  return res;
})
console.log(iterate)
```

```js
const people = [{
    name: "mike",
    jobs: ["waiter", "doctor"]
  },
  {
    name: "nils",
    jobs: ["singer", "actor"]
  },
  {
    name: "nils",
    jobs: ["nurse", "actor"]
  },
]

let res = []
const iterate = people.map(person => {
  return person.jobs.map(job => {
    res.push(job)
  })
  return res;
})
console.log(iterate)
```

Comment: Looks like `return` statement is missing in you `map` function

Comment: The first example is working (though possibly not as you intended it to). In your second example you're pushing results into `res` (and are not returning anything, resulting in those `undefined`s in the returned mapped array) but are logging `iterate`; I suspect you meant `console.log(res)` there.

Comment: could you explain to me why in exampe 1 I am returning the arrays and not the values inside? Also, is there a way I can do it without pushing into res and returning it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code reformats the data from an array of objects into a new array of arrays. Each inner array now contains the jobs of a specific person.

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: "mike",
    jobs: ["waiter", "doctor"]
  },
  {
    name: "nils",
    jobs: ["singer", "actor"]
  },
  {
    name: "nils",
    jobs: ["nurse", "actor"]
  }
];

const iterate = [].concat(...people.map(person => person.jobs));
console.log(iterate);
```

Answer (score 1):

- I don't know much fancy way of writing this, but here is my solution.
- You want to extracts jobs from people array of object.
- What I did below is just created one variable to store job values.
- Loop thour array of object and looped though jobs key value of each person and pushed it inside that array we have created.

```js
const people = [{
    name: "mike",
    jobs: ["waiter", "doctor"]
  },
  {
    name: "nils",
    jobs: ["singer", "actor"]
  },
  {
    name: "nils",
    jobs: ["nurse", "actor"]
  },
]

const jobs = [];
people.forEach(person => {
  person.jobs.forEach(job => {
    jobs.push(job);
  })
})
console.log(jobs)
```

Comment: Updated my answer, thanks for correcting @pilchard

Answer (score 0):

Another approach using `.flat(Infinity)` method:

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: "mike",
    jobs: ["waiter", "doctor"]
  },
  {
    name: "nils",
    jobs: ["singer", "actor"]
  },
  {
    name: "nils",
    jobs: ["nurse", "actor"]
  }
];

const iterate = people.map(person => person.jobs).flat(Infinity)
console.log(iterate);
```

Comment: just `flatMap` you don't need `Infinity` just a single level of flattening. Also why did you post two answers?

Answer (score -2):

Thanks to @pilchard for the suggestion `flatMap`:

```js
const people = [
  {
    name: "mike",
    jobs: ["waiter", "doctor"]
  },
  {
    name: "nils",
    jobs: ["singer", "actor"]
  },
  {
    name: "nils",
    jobs: ["nurse", "actor"]
  }
];
const iterate = people.flatMap(person => person.jobs)
console.log(iterate);
```

Comment: It is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48435515/how-to-flatten-nested-array-of-object-using-es6) vote to close. Also if you have more than one suggestion simply put them in one answer.